# How to solve button sum with loop JFrame

Tags: java, for-loop, button, jframe, actionlistener

How do I make the action listener sum the loop above? What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should put the sum in the first loop than the other in the action listener. Or is there something wrong with my action listener? Could someone point out my mistake, please.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Bton extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JPanel pan = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
JLabel []lab = new JLabel[4];
JTextField []text = new JTextField[4];
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.grey,1);
JButton b = new JButton("Calculate");

public Bton() {
    initComponents();
    pan.setLayout(null);

    for(int i=0; i<lab.length ;i++){
        lab[i] = new JLabel();
        text[i] = new JTextField();

        lab[i].setBounds(new Rectangle(15,(i+1)*40, 60, 25));
        lab[i].setText("Box #" + (i+1));
        lab[i].setBorder(border);
        text[i].setBounds(new Rectangle(100,(i+1)*40, 60, 25));

        pan.add(lab[i],null);
        pan.add(text[i],null);

        setSize(200,420);
        setTitle("Sum tab.");
    }

    JLabel labe = new JLabel();
    labe.setBounds(new Rectangle(15, 330, 60, 25));
    labe.setText("Total Sum");
    labe.setBorder(border);
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(6);
    txt.setBounds(new Rectangle(100, 330, 60, 25));

    b.setBounds(70, 290, 89, 23);
    add(b);
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<lab.length ;i++){
                sum =+ Integer.parseInt(text[i].getText());
            }
            txt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));                
        }
    });        
    pan.add(labe);
    pan.add(txt);
}
```